# Python -> reminder not popping

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, reminders

I am doing a project on a notification program that reads an excel file as you edit it and then sends a notification on the time you set the reminder.
The code is here:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from plyer import notification


def remind(title, message):
    notification.notify(title=title, message=message, timeout=10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        df = pd.read_excel("./reminder.xlsx")
        for index, item in df.iterrows():
            time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            if time == item['Time']:
                remind(item['Title'], item['Message'])
            else:
                continue
```

The program is running fine but the reminder is not popping up
i am working on python 3.7.9 on win8 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

```
from numpy import nan
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from plyer import notification
import time


def notifyMe(title, message,icon):
    notification.notify(
        title=title, 
        message=message, 
        app_icon = icon,
        timeout=10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    notifyMe("Hello","We are in together in these tough time","virusicon.ico")

    df = pd.read_excel("reminder.xlsx")
    df["Icon"] = df["Icon"].astype(str)  
    df["Heading"] = df["Heading"].astype(str)
    df["Message"] = df["Message"].astype(str)

    number_of_rows = len(df.index)

    while True:
        flag = True
        for item in range(0,number_of_rows):
            now = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"),"%H:%M:%S")
            x = datetime.datetime.strptime(df['Time'][item].strftime("%H:%M:%S"),"%H:%M:%S")
            if x==now:
                print(True)
                print(df['Heading'][item], df['Message'][item],df["Icon"][item])
                if df["Icon"][item]=="nan":
                    df["Icon"][item]=""
                if df["Message"][item]=="nan":
                    df["Message"][item]=""
                if df["Heading"][item]=="nan":
                    df["Heading"][item]=""
                notifyMe(df['Heading'][item], df['Message'][item],df['Icon'][item])
                time.sleep(1)
            if  now<=x:
                flag = False
        if flag:
            exit()
```

[Format of the xslx file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32tj6.png)

You can try this. It may help you